# Content type issue when translate xml to json using WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I found some message may lose when transfer xml content to json. For example, a webservice passed a value "80e5" and it can be display in xml response properly. However, when I use "" to transfer the response from xml to json, the "80e5" automatically translated to 8000000, from "STRING" to "INTEGER".

The version of ESB I tried are 4.9.0 and 4.8.1 and I tried both JsonStreamFormatter and JsonFormatter mentioned in the online document, but didn't work. I want to know if there is a node or attribute can be used to define the type of a node, because the different display of INTEGER and STRING will result in a difficulty for users to parse the data.

Comment: can you add the synapse-config here?

Comment: I simply use the property mediator to do transformation. Like`<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>`

Comment: As I understood u r trying to convert `<a>...<m>80e5</m>...</a>` type xml to json as follows, `{a:{...{m:80e5}...}}` but 80e5 get changed to 800000 which is in decimal right? if so one alternative you can try is first store the value by reading the xml to a new property and then reassign it to json body later.

Comment: yes , that will definitely work, but the difficulty is, this 80e5 value is in an array, the structure is like `<a>....<ID>80e5</ID><ID>30s3</ID>....</a>`. I don't think I can locate where is the 80e5 value.

Comment: Besides, this value is replied by the backend webservice, which means I cannot predict when and where this kind of value will apear.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample scenario with wso2 ESB 4.8.1 and i was resulted with the conversion of "80e5" as follow when the JsonFormatter is enabled:

```
  DEBUG - wire << "{"test":{"value":8.0E+6}}"
```

I was able to get the 80e5 as it is when the JSONMessageFormatter is enabled in axis2.xml file.
The result was:

```
 DEBUG - wire << "{"test":{"value":"80e5"}}[\r][\n]"
```

Hope this will help..

Comment: Thanks for ur help, could you show me how to tell the JsonFormatter the type for each node?

Comment: I tried the JSONMessageFormatter, and it gave me the 80e5 result. However, the `<?xml-multiple?>` function is disabled which I used to tell message formatter that this is an array. Anyway, thanks for your help.